# General report of couple tables with inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I need to create a general report about of a trucks in a company.

I have this tables in my schema:

Schema image:

[image]

Basically, I need to create a table containing the following:

|Location|Trucks|TotalOfCampaings|CampaingsWithCompleteStatus|CampaingsWithInProcessStatus|

- **Location**: Location of the trucks, are in the Truck table.
- **Trucks**: Number of Trucks by Location.
- **TotalOfCampaings**: Total Number of Campaings by the Location and Trucks.
- **CampaingsWithCompleteStatus**: Total Number of Campaings Completed, the status are in the table Campaing Control.
- **CampaingsWithInProcessStatus**: Total Number of Campaings not finished.

Campaing = Order to fix one or multiple trucks.

I tried with a inner joins querys, but i cant get what i expect for the general report.

I would appreciate help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    -- Prepare the base data for the report
    (SELECT location, COUNT(*) AS Trucks FROM Truck GROUP BY location) loc
    -- The statistics needed, make sure it is 1 to 1
    -- The status value just guess as you did not mention in the question
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS TotalOfCampaings, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithCompleteStatus, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN cc.campaing_status = 'InProcess' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CampaingsWithInProcessStatus
        FROM CampaingControl cc INNER JOIN Truck t ON cc.vin = t.vin 
        WHERE t.location = loc.location
    ) stat
```

Comment: Eric I appreciate so much your help, your query works perfectly. :)

Comment: Eric, one more question, i need to count in the Trucks Column, only the trucks with one or more campaings, doesn't matter if the campaing are completed or in process.

Comment: @TimeToCode If you need to convert the `NULL` to 0, you can use `ISNULL(, 0)` in the `SELECT` statement